# Can psi attack damage be reduced?

Tags: xcom-2

The Will stat helps soldiers resist negative mental status effects from psi attacks such as mind control.

However, there are some psi attacks that merely do damage, such as the AOE psi attack of the Gatekeeper.

**Does the Will stat help reduce the amount of damage taken from these attacks?** If not, is there *anything* that can help protect our soldiers against direct damage psi attacks? Armor certainly doesn't help, since psi attacks bypass armor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about anything that can help with psi attacks. Both **Mind Shield** and **Solace** are helpful against all psi attacks other than attacks that do direct damage.

The psi attack amount is more related to the enemy's Psi Offense Rating.

**In this case offense is your best defense. Use flashbangs or other ways to disorient enemies. This will restrict all their special abilities.**

Comment: Or just kill them immediately. That restricts their abilities as well.

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, that should work as well :)